Injective continuous endomorphisms of the unit circle are only the involutions
As done here An injective continuous self-map of the unit circle is a homeomorphism, one can show that any continuous injective homomorphism from the unit circle to itself must be surjective.
Now, noting that the circle has only one element of order 2, we should be able to conclude that the only continuous automorphisms of the circle are the involutions, i.e. the identity and f(x) = -x, for all x.
How to conclude this? Why does it hold?

What do you mean by order 2?

Considering the circle as a topological group. The book by Morris gives this hint, in order to solve it, but I am not sure how to use it. Or, generally, how to conclude that the only continuous automorphisms of the circle are the involutions.

When you say automorphism, do you mean automorphism as a topological group, which are essentially by definition a homeomorphism (and a group isomorphism)? I don't see what this has to do with the statement that continuous injections are homeomorphisms.

The problem was phrased so that our assumption is that f is a continuous group monomorphism. By continuity, we obtain that it is an isomorphism. Hence, now we have to show that the only continuous group automorphisms are the identity and the involution (which are clearly homeomorphisms). I think that the book I am using wishes to refrain from the use of covering spaces. Do you happen to know how?

If you're trying to show that the only topological group automorphisms of $S^1$ are the identity and $x \mapsto x^{-1}$, I suggest using the universal cover $p: \mathbf{R} \to S^1$. Any such automorphism must lift uniquely to an automorphism of $\mathbf{R}$ and also take the generator $1$ of $\pi_1(S^1) \cong \mathbf{Z} = p^{-1}(1)$ to either $1$ or $-1$. But a continuous group endomorphism of $\mathbf{R}$ is determined by where it sends $1$ since $\mathbf{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbf{R}$.

Hi, thank you very much! Yes, I am familiar with this answer. Do you know if it possible to work without covering spaces?
